# Convert 4 digits into a DateTime (Year + padded with minimum values)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I am writing a script to return a formatted date based on user input, which can be :

- 2016
- 2016/11
- 2016/11/10
- 2016/11/10 24

Basically I have to pad these input with the minimum possible values. (2016 returns 2016/01/01 00:00:00).

I've tried doing it with `date -d "2016"` but this returns the time 8:16pm on today's date

Many thanks!!

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: (2016 returns 2016/01/01 00:00:00).... it's in there :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that should basically do what you want to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo INPUT:$1

[[ "$1" == "" ]] && YEAR=2016
[[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]{4}$ ]] && YEAR="$1"
[[ $YEAR == "" ]] && YEAR=`echo "$1" | grep -Po ".*(?=/[0-9]{2}/)"`
MONTH=`echo "$1" | grep -Po "(?<=[0-9]{4}/).*(?=/[0-9]{2})"`
DAY=`echo "$1" | grep -Po "(?<=/[0-9]{2}/).*(?=\ )"`
HR=`echo "$1" | grep -Po "(?<=[0-9]{2}\ ).*"`
MIN="00"
SEC="00"
[[ "$MONTH" == "" ]] && MONTH="01"
[[ "$DAY" == "" ]] && DAY="01"
[[ "$HR" == "" ]] && HR="00"

echo $YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY $HR:$MIN:$SEC
```

Please note that this is a basic skeleton, you will have to add your own border cases and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date command to get your output like below

d1=`date +%Y`           #Output is 2016
d2=`date +%Y/%m`        #Output is 2016/11
d3=`date +%Y/%m/%d`     #Output is 2016/11/10
d4=`date +%Y/%m/%d\t%H` #Output is 2016 -> \t-tab specified,if you want the whole time you can use "%X or %T" instead of "%H"

echo $d1
echo $d2
echo $d3
echo $d4

Comment: For user input date, do like take the input from used and save it in a variable and fetch 4 times as per your output by using cut or sed command